# RTF Field from Service Cloud in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, richtextarea, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm facing some troubles with personalized contents in email.

I have  Marketing cloud connected to Service Cloud and I need to fetch a RTA field from Opportunity (standard service cloud object) in my email.
I synchronized Service Cloud Object in my marketing cloud and now I have the resulting synchronized Data extension.

Now for my email (and customer Journey) I try to set up an automation to pull my data from synchronized data extension into an new data extension by a query activity.

Everything works fine but the RTA field is never populated in  teh new data extension.

I need to retrieve this field in the email because it contains the url of an image I need to display in the email.
The image should be different for every customer so I need to use AMP Script too.

Comment: Can you provide what you have so far? This post is currently in the queue to be closed, as it lacks enough detail/is not specific enough to answer as a self-contained question. I would also be interested to hear from the two people who upvoted this as to why - as it's currently written (and hopefully OP can improve it!), this is a cookie cutter example of questions we should not be encouraging

Comment: I try to import  service cloud record with all fields including this one (RTA field). But I am not able to see this field. This field is just visible in synchronized data extension but unfortunately it's impossibile to use those DE in email personalization. So I'm wondering if anyone could have an idea.